# How can I save the progress of a game in Visual Basic 2010?

Tags: save, vb.net-2010

I have created a hidden objects game, like this one: http://www.shazaml.com/archives/creating-a-hidden-object-game-in-silverlight-3,  where the player has to find about 60 objects within a picture. There are eight labels, each populated with a string that contains the name of an object to find. This is taken from pictureArray().

```
 Sub pictureArray()

    Randomize()

    pictures.Add("Cat")
    pictures.Add("Spade")
    pictures.Add("Butterfly")
    pictures.Add("Shoes")
    pictures.Add("Radio")
    pictures.Add("Grasshopper")
    pictures.Add("Lamp")
    pictures.Add("Coconut")
    pictures.Add("Clock")
    pictures.Add("Lightbulb")
    pictures.Add("Binoculars")
    pictures.Add("Diamond")
    pictures.Add("Hammer")
    pictures.Add("Bell")
    pictures.Add("Snail")
    pictures.Add("Bag")
    pictures.Add("Camera")
    pictures.Add("Pencil")
    pictures.Add("Horseshoe")
    pictures.Add("Brush")
    pictures.Add("Gloves")
    pictures.Add("Ball")
    pictures.Add("Umbrella")
    pictures.Add("Gnome")
    pictures.Add("Mouse")
    pictures.Add("Crown")
    pictures.Add("Torch")
    pictures.Add("Paperclip")
    pictures.Add("Handprint")
    pictures.Add("Hat")
    pictures.Add("Car")
    pictures.Add("Star")
    pictures.Add("Wheel")
    pictures.Add("Book")
    pictures.Add("Triangle")
    pictures.Add("Die")
    pictures.Add("Glasses")
    pictures.Add("One")
    pictures.Add("Shell")
    pictures.Add("Apple")
    pictures.Add("Bowling Pin")
    pictures.Add("Spoon")
    pictures.Add("Magnifier")
    pictures.Add("Letter R")
    pictures.Add("Aeroplane")
    pictures.Add("Scissors")
    pictures.Add("Mask")
    pictures.Add("Bow")
    pictures.Add("Coin")
    pictures.Add("Frog")
    pictures.Add("Snake")
    pictures.Add("Key")
    pictures.Add("Rope")
    pictures.Add("Peg")
    pictures.Add("Bottle")
    pictures.Add("Belt")
    pictures.Add("Angel")
    pictures.Add("Pawprint")
    pictures.Add("Clover")
    pictures.Add("Phone")
    pictures.Add("Ring")

    lblOne.Text = (pictures(RandIndex))
    pictures.RemoveAt(RandIndex)
    RandIndex = RandGen.Next(0, pictures.Count)

    lblTwo.Text = (pictures(RandIndex))
    pictures.RemoveAt(RandIndex)
    RandIndex = RandGen.Next(0, pictures.Count)

    lblThree.Text = (pictures(RandIndex))
    pictures.RemoveAt(RandIndex)
    RandIndex = RandGen.Next(0, pictures.Count)

    lblFour.Text = (pictures(RandIndex))
    pictures.RemoveAt(RandIndex)
    RandIndex = RandGen.Next(0, pictures.Count)

    lblFive.Text = (pictures(RandIndex))
    pictures.RemoveAt(RandIndex)
    RandIndex = RandGen.Next(0, pictures.Count)

    lblSix.Text = (pictures(RandIndex))
    pictures.RemoveAt(RandIndex)
    RandIndex = RandGen.Next(0, pictures.Count)

    lblSeven.Text = (pictures(RandIndex))
    pictures.RemoveAt(RandIndex)
    RandIndex = RandGen.Next(0, pictures.Count)

    lblEight.Text = (pictures(RandIndex))
    pictures.RemoveAt(RandIndex)
    RandIndex = RandGen.Next(0, pictures.Count)

End Sub
```

As there are a lot of objects to find, the player may want to quit the game and return to it at a later date, therefore, I was wondering what's the best way I could save the current progress of the game so that the player can pick up from where they left off?

I have done some research, trying to find a way online, but didn't understand it or know what would be best for this game?

Answer (score 1):

Basically you would create a CLASS to hold the List(Of String) and each of the Eight current values in your Labels.  Then use XmlSerializer to save and load that information to an XML file.

Here is a very simple example:

```
Public Class Form1

    Private RandGen As New Random
    Private Pictures As New List(Of String)
    Private DataFile As String = System.IO.Path.Combine(My.Computer.FileSystem.SpecialDirectories.CurrentUserApplicationData, "GameState.xml")

    Sub pictureArray()
        Pictures.Clear()
        pictures.Add("Cat")
        pictures.Add("Spade")
        pictures.Add("Butterfly")
        pictures.Add("Shoes")
        pictures.Add("Radio")
        pictures.Add("Grasshopper")
        pictures.Add("Lamp")
        pictures.Add("Coconut")
        pictures.Add("Clock")
        pictures.Add("Lightbulb")
        pictures.Add("Binoculars")
        pictures.Add("Diamond")
        pictures.Add("Hammer")
        pictures.Add("Bell")
        pictures.Add("Snail")
        pictures.Add("Bag")
        pictures.Add("Camera")
        pictures.Add("Pencil")
        pictures.Add("Horseshoe")
        pictures.Add("Brush")
        pictures.Add("Gloves")
        pictures.Add("Ball")
        pictures.Add("Umbrella")
        pictures.Add("Gnome")
        pictures.Add("Mouse")
        pictures.Add("Crown")
        pictures.Add("Torch")
        pictures.Add("Paperclip")
        pictures.Add("Handprint")
        pictures.Add("Hat")
        pictures.Add("Car")
        pictures.Add("Star")
        pictures.Add("Wheel")
        pictures.Add("Book")
        pictures.Add("Triangle")
        pictures.Add("Die")
        pictures.Add("Glasses")
        pictures.Add("One")
        pictures.Add("Shell")
        pictures.Add("Apple")
        pictures.Add("Bowling Pin")
        pictures.Add("Spoon")
        pictures.Add("Magnifier")
        pictures.Add("Letter R")
        pictures.Add("Aeroplane")
        pictures.Add("Scissors")
        pictures.Add("Mask")
        pictures.Add("Bow")
        pictures.Add("Coin")
        pictures.Add("Frog")
        pictures.Add("Snake")
        pictures.Add("Key")
        pictures.Add("Rope")
        pictures.Add("Peg")
        pictures.Add("Bottle")
        pictures.Add("Belt")
        pictures.Add("Angel")
        pictures.Add("Pawprint")
        pictures.Add("Clover")
        pictures.Add("Phone")
        pictures.Add("Ring")

        Dim RandIndex As Integer
        lblOne.Text = (pictures(RandIndex))
        pictures.RemoveAt(RandIndex)
        RandIndex = RandGen.Next(0, pictures.Count)

        lblTwo.Text = (pictures(RandIndex))
        pictures.RemoveAt(RandIndex)
        RandIndex = RandGen.Next(0, pictures.Count)

        lblThree.Text = (pictures(RandIndex))
        pictures.RemoveAt(RandIndex)
        RandIndex = RandGen.Next(0, pictures.Count)

        lblFour.Text = (pictures(RandIndex))
        pictures.RemoveAt(RandIndex)
        RandIndex = RandGen.Next(0, pictures.Count)

        lblFive.Text = (pictures(RandIndex))
        pictures.RemoveAt(RandIndex)
        RandIndex = RandGen.Next(0, pictures.Count)

        lblSix.Text = (pictures(RandIndex))
        pictures.RemoveAt(RandIndex)
        RandIndex = RandGen.Next(0, pictures.Count)

        lblSeven.Text = (pictures(RandIndex))
        pictures.RemoveAt(RandIndex)
        RandIndex = RandGen.Next(0, pictures.Count)

        lblEight.Text = (pictures(RandIndex))
        pictures.RemoveAt(RandIndex)
        RandIndex = RandGen.Next(0, pictures.Count)
    End Sub

    Private Sub btnSave_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnSave.Click
        Dim gs As New GameState
        gs.Pictures = Pictures
        gs.lblOne = lblOne.Text
        gs.lblTwo = lblTwo.Text
        gs.lblThree = lblThree.Text
        gs.lblFour = lblFour.Text
        gs.lblFive = lblFive.Text
        gs.lblSix = lblSix.Text
        gs.lblSeven = lblSeven.Text
        gs.lblEight = lblEight.Text

        Try
            Dim xml As New System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer(gs.GetType)
            Using fs As New System.IO.FileStream(DataFile, IO.FileMode.OpenOrCreate, IO.FileAccess.Write)
                xml.Serialize(fs, gs)
            End Using
            MessageBox.Show("Game Saved!")
        Catch ex As Exception
            MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString, "Error Saving Game")
        End Try
    End Sub

    Private Sub btnLoad_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnLoad.Click
        If System.IO.File.Exists(DataFile) Then
            Try
                Dim gs As GameState
                Dim xml As New System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer(GetType(GameState))
                Using fs As New System.IO.FileStream(DataFile, IO.FileMode.Open, IO.FileAccess.Read)
                    gs = DirectCast(xml.Deserialize(fs), GameState)
                    Pictures = gs.Pictures
                    lblOne.Text = gs.lblOne
                    lblTwo.Text = gs.lblTwo
                    lblThree.Text = gs.lblThree
                    lblFour.Text = gs.lblFour
                    lblFive.Text = gs.lblFive
                    lblSix.Text = gs.lblSix
                    lblSeven.Text = gs.lblSeven
                    lblEight.Text = gs.lblEight
                    MessageBox.Show("Game Loaded!")
                End Using
            Catch ex As Exception
                MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString, "Error Loading Game")
            End Try
        Else
            MessageBox.Show("No Saved Game Found")
        End If
    End Sub

End Class

<Serializable()> _
Public Class GameState
    Public Pictures As New List(Of String)
    Public lblOne As String
    Public lblTwo As String
    Public lblThree As String
    Public lblFour As String
    Public lblFive As String
    Public lblSix As String
    Public lblSeven As String
    Public lblEight As String
End Class
```